# Modify CucumberOptions tags when running Cucumber in Java

Tags: java, bdd, cucumber-java

I was wondering if there was a way to modify CucumberOptions tags while Cucumber is running?

I'm not sure if this is possible or not but I was wondering if there was a way to modify tags while Cucumber is running. In my example code, I would like to add another tag "@Login" once Cucumber runs. I am trying to setup a configuration where I can select which feature I want to run without going into the Runner class.

**Settings Class**

```
 String AddTags = "@Login";
          set = new HashMap<String, String>(){
            {put("Tags", AddTags);
```

**Runner**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@CucumberOptions (features="src/test/cucumber/features", 
tags = "@Smoke",  //For instance, once cucumber runs I want to add 
tag "@Login". //So something like adding Settings.set.get("Tags");
plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber- 
htmlreport","json:target/cucumber-report.json"}
)
public class Runner {

}
```

Not sure if this is possible with Cucumber but wanted to ask.

Comment: Once the runner is triggered, there is no way of changing the tags at runtime. Can you expand on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a list of tags?

```
tags = "@Smoke,@Login"
```

Comment: Does this work with newer versions of Cucumber? Version 4.x took a list like this: {"tag1", "tag2"}, after I upgraded to version 7 the parameter is a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Tag expressions](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions) to combine several tags, for example:

```
**Expression        Description**
@fast               Scenarios tagged with @fast
@wip and not @slow  Scenarios tagged with @wip that aren’t also tagged with @slow
@smoke and @fast    Scenarios tagged with both @smoke and @fast
@gui or @database   Scenarios tagged with either @gui or @database
```